# Random keyboard key assignment corruption in Windows XP

Tags: keyboard, key, transpose

> #### Manually Migrated to Super User:
>
> [Random keyboard key assignment corruption in Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/158563/random-keyboard-key-assignment-corruption-in-windows-xp)

This isn't a programming question but I'll try to get away with it.  WinXP SP3 machine.  Every so often (sometimes several times a day) my keyboard (or Windows, or something) decides that it is going to translate the keys I am typing.  It's always the same behaviour : specifically

- Q and A are transposed.
- W and Z are transposed.
- the digit keys (the row below the F1-F12 keys) become random punctuation characters.

and several other random shufflings of keys occur.  Interestingly:

- the numeric keypad still works
- the corruptions are always associated with a
  particular application.  Exiting the application (e.g.
  Delphi, or Chrome), and restarting the app. cures the problem.
- the same problem occurs on my laptop at home, I guess because I run the same apps.
- Ctl-Q and Ctl-A are also transposed

I'm convinced that something I'm running is trashing something but I have no idea where to look.  I'm hoping someone reads this and says "oh yeah..."

Yes, I have AV software running.

Comment: Would be a great question on SuperUser.

Comment: This really belongs on superuser.com - you're likely to get better answers there :)

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/158563/random-keyboard-key-assignment-corruption-in-windows-xp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application may have been (accidentally) setup to use either a different locale, a particular IME (Input Method Editor) or a different keyboard layout.

Do you have the Language Bar showing? (under `Keyboards and Languages` in the `Regional and Language Options` in Control Panel on Vista).

Make sure its visible, check out the current settings. Checking the `Show additional language bar icons in the taskbar` option may be useful too.

Then launch the offending application and see if the selected locale/keyboard/IME changes. If so change it back to the usual one.

Comment: That might explain it if the transposition was permanent every time I ran the app, but it happens randomly and spontaneously with no warning.

Comment: Here's the answer : http://superuser.com/questions/158563/random-keyboard-key-assignment-corruption-in-windows-xp

Comment: Ah, glad to see I was on the right track :-)